# How to impute missing data within a date range in a table?

Tags: python, r, algorithm

I have the following problem with imputing the missing or zero values in a table. It seems like it's more of an algorithm problem. I wanted to know if someone could help me out figure this out in python or R.

```
Asset  Mileage      Date
-----------------------------------
A   41,084        01/26/2017 00:00:00
A   0             01/24/2017 00:00:00
A   0             01/23/2017 00:00:00
A   40,864        01/19/2017 00:00:00
A   0             01/18/2017 00:00:00
B   5,000         01/13/2017 00:00:00
B   0             01/12/2017 00:00:00
B   0             01/11/2017 00:00:00
B   0             01/10/2017 00:00:00
B   0             01/09/2017 00:00:00
B   2,000         01/07/2017 00:00:00
```

for each asset(A,B,etc..) traverse through the records chronologically(date) replace all the zeros with the average of mileage between the points =

> (earlier mileage that is not zero - later mileage that is not zero) /
>   ( number of records from the earlier mileage to the later mileage) +
>   the earlier mileage.

for instance for the above table the data will look like this after it's fixed

```
Asset  Mileage      Date
-----------------------------------
A   41,084  01/26/2017 00:00:00
A   40,974  01/24/2017 00:00:00
A   40,919  01/23/2017 00:00:00 
A   40,864  01/19/2017 00:00:00
A   39,800  01/18/2017 00:00:00
B   5,000   01/13/2017 00:00:00
B   4,000   01/12/2017 00:00:00
B   3,500   01/11/2017 00:00:00
B   3,000   01/10/2017 00:00:00
B   2,500   01/09/2017 00:00:00
B   2,000   01/07/2017 00:00:00
```

in the above case for instance the calculation for one of the records is as below:

> (41084-40864)/4(# of records from 40,864 to 41,084) = 110 + previous
>   value(40,864) = 40919

Comment: "help me figure this out" is not a Stack Overflow question.  You have one algorithm in your posting; others are readily available in a browser search.  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service, so I'm not sure what you want from us.

Comment: @Prune I think this is a good question.  He gives the original data, describes the desired result, then asks how to implement it in R.  He's not asking if there's a better algorithm, just how to code the one he mentions.

Comment: @NathanWerth: "write this code for me" is not an acceptable question.  "more of an algorithm problem" and "impute" suggest to me that OP is also looking for another algorithm, such as date-based interpolation or perhaps non-linear fitting.  If this were a simple matter of writing the expression OP gave, reviewing a tutorial on basic math (in Python or R) would solve the problem.  Given no code whatsoever (e.g. no table structure), this seems to me as a request to write the entire block of code -- and hence my down-vote.

Comment: @Prune. As NathanWerth, noticed. I made an effort to present the the calculations and desired output. However, I cannot anticipate your assumptions on what I want. I think, The better way of responding would be " this is how you can go about solving this problem...." and provide any input that would help.

Comment: Having a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be helpful here. "Here's what I've tried" can be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to be using an analysis method that uses some sort of `by` to iterate over your data frame and find averages. You could consider something using `by()` and `apply()`. The specific iterative changes make it harder without adding in an ordered variable (i.e., right now your rows are implied to be numbered, but should be numbered by date within asset).

Steps to solving this yourself:

1. Create an ordered variable that provides a number from mileage (0) to mileage (X).
2. Use either `by()` or `dplyr::group_by()` to create averages within each asset. You might want to `merge()` or `dplyr::inner_join()` that to the original dataset, or use a lookup.
3. Use `ifelse()` to add that average to rows where mileage is 0, multiplying it by the ordered variable.